# How to Use PIVOT with tables joined from two databases in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I am getting data after joined two databases, first is "listserver" and second is "newsletter".

Here is my original query which returns 4 records for one subscriber.

```
select 
    gmin. MEMBER_PROPERTY,gmin .MEMBER_VALUE , m.*  
from 
    SUBSCRIBER s
inner join 
    listserv.dbo .MEMBER m on m.MEMBER_EMAIL= s.SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL
inner join 
    listserv.dbo .MEMBER_ATTRIBUTES gmin on gmin.MEMBER_ID= m.MEMBER_ID
where 
    s .SUBSCRIBER_GROUP  like '%abc%' 
order by 
    m.MEMBER_DATE_ADDED desc
```

This query returns 4 rows for a single subscribers as I have 4 entries in "**MEMBER_ATTRIBUTES**" table.

Here is the structure

[image]

Now I want to get this data in one row for each subscriber. I know I can do it using PIVOT, but i don't know how to use PIVOT with above query.

Please help me how can i achieve my goal, thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** I want result in below format:

[image: I want result in this format]

Comment: I'm maybe not sure it's PIVOT you're after - could you give an example of how the 'result' should be?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen please check i have updated the question with the  required output screenshot

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/11122225/2806972 may be its help you.

Comment: You need dynamic pivot here. Pls provide some sample data (in script form, not as a screenshot!) to get a query you need. I could also give you a generalized sample you could work from.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below query to achieve my goal. [Use PIVOT for Multiple records in SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107230/use-pivot-for-multiple-records-in-sql-server/23108093?noredirect=1#23108093)  and [Getting Null data while using PIVOT in sql server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101039/getting-null-data-while-using-pivot-in-sql-server-2008-r2) questions has helped me to build this query.

```
CREATE Table   #MEMBER_ATTRIBUTES   (
MEMBER_ID int,
MEMBER_PROPERTY varchar( 500 ),
MEMBER_VALUE varchar( 500 ),
PRMEDIAUSER_ID int,
MEMBER_FULL_NAME nvarchar(500),
MEMBER_LAST_NAME  nvarchar(500),
MEMBER_MID_INIT nvarchar(500),
MEMBER_FIRST_NAME nvarchar(500),
MEMBER_EMAIL nvarchar(500),
MEMBER_FAX nvarchar(500),
MEMBER_SEND_BY_FAX nvarchar(500),
MEMBER_LANGUAGE nvarchar(500),
COUNTRY_ID int,
MEMBER_ACTIVE int,
MEMBER_DATE_ADDED datetime,
MEMBER_COMPANY  nvarchar(500),
MEMBER_ADDRESS nvarchar(500),
MEMBER_CITY nvarchar(500),
MEMBER_STATE nvarchar(500),
MEMBER_ZIP nvarchar(500),
MEMBER_POSTALCODE nvarchar(500),
MEMBER_PHONE nvarchar(500),
MEMBER_NEAREST_AIRPORT nvarchar(500),
MEMBER_OCCUPATION nvarchar(500),
MEMBER_COUNTY nvarchar(500)
)
insert INTO #MEMBER_ATTRIBUTES ( MEMBER_ID ,MEMBER_PROPERTY
, MEMBER_VALUE,PRMEDIAUSER_ID,MEMBER_FULL_NAME,MEMBER_LAST_NAME,MEMBER_MID_INIT,MEMBER_FIRST_NAME,
MEMBER_EMAIL,MEMBER_FAX,MEMBER_SEND_BY_FAX ,MEMBER_LANGUAGE ,COUNTRY_ID ,MEMBER_ACTIVE ,MEMBER_DATE_ADDED ,
MEMBER_COMPANY  ,MEMBER_ADDRESS ,MEMBER_CITY ,MEMBER_STATE ,MEMBER_ZIP ,MEMBER_POSTALCODE ,
MEMBER_PHONE ,MEMBER_NEAREST_AIRPORT ,MEMBER_OCCUPATION ,MEMBER_COUNTY 
) select isnull( m.MEMBER_ID ,'0' ),
ISNULL ( [gmin].[MEMBER_PROPERTY] , '''') AS MEMBER_PROPERTY
, ISNULL( [gmin].[MEMBER_VALUE] ,'''' ) AS MEMBER_VALUE,
m.PRMEDIAUSER_ID,m.MEMBER_FULL_NAME,m.MEMBER_LAST_NAME,m.MEMBER_MID_INIT ,
m.MEMBER_FIRST_NAME,
m.MEMBER_EMAIL,m.MEMBER_FAX ,m.MEMBER_SEND_BY_FAX,m.MEMBER_LANGUAGE ,
m.COUNTRY_ID ,m.MEMBER_ACTIVE,m.MEMBER_DATE_ADDED,m.MEMBER_COMPANY ,
m.MEMBER_ADDRESS ,m.MEMBER_CITY,m.MEMBER_STATE ,m.MEMBER_ZIP ,
m.MEMBER_POSTALCODE,m.MEMBER_PHONE ,m.MEMBER_NEAREST_AIRPORT ,
m.MEMBER_OCCUPATION,m.MEMBER_COUNTY 
from SUBSCRIBER s
inner join listserv.dbo .MEMBER m on m.MEMBER_EMAIL= s.SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL
left join listserv.dbo .MEMBER_ATTRIBUTES gmin on gmin.MEMBER_ID= m.MEMBER_ID
 where s .SUBSCRIBER_GROUP  like '%abc%' and m.MEMBER_ACTIVE=1 
--select * from #MEMBER_ATTRIBUTES
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR( MAX ),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR ( MAX)
SELECT @cols= stuff((
    SELECT distinct ', ' +QUOTENAME ( MAX( MEMBER_PROPERTY ))
    FROM #MEMBER_ATTRIBUTES
    group by MEMBER_VALUE
    --order by MEMBER_VALUE
    FOR XML PATH( '' )), 1 , 2, '');
SET @query = 'SELECT MEMBER_ID,
PRMEDIAUSER_ID,
MEMBER_FULL_NAME,
MEMBER_LAST_NAME,
MEMBER_MID_INIT ,
MEMBER_FIRST_NAME,
MEMBER_EMAIL,
MEMBER_FAX ,
MEMBER_SEND_BY_FAX,
MEMBER_LANGUAGE ,
COUNTRY_ID ,
MEMBER_ACTIVE,
MEMBER_DATE_ADDED,
MEMBER_COMPANY ,
MEMBER_ADDRESS ,
MEMBER_CITY,
MEMBER_STATE ,
MEMBER_ZIP ,
MEMBER_POSTALCODE,
MEMBER_PHONE ,
MEMBER_NEAREST_AIRPORT ,
MEMBER_OCCUPATION,
MEMBER_COUNTY  ' + @cols + '
from
     (
           SELECT MEMBER_ID,MEMBER_VALUE,MEMBER_PROPERTY,PRMEDIAUSER_ID,
MEMBER_FULL_NAME,
MEMBER_LAST_NAME,
MEMBER_MID_INIT ,
MEMBER_FIRST_NAME,
MEMBER_EMAIL,
MEMBER_FAX ,
MEMBER_SEND_BY_FAX,
MEMBER_LANGUAGE ,
COUNTRY_ID ,
MEMBER_ACTIVE,
MEMBER_DATE_ADDED,
MEMBER_COMPANY ,
MEMBER_ADDRESS ,
MEMBER_CITY,
MEMBER_STATE ,
MEMBER_ZIP ,
MEMBER_POSTALCODE,
MEMBER_PHONE ,
MEMBER_NEAREST_AIRPORT ,
MEMBER_OCCUPATION,
MEMBER_COUNTY  FROM #MEMBER_ATTRIBUTES       ) x
    pivot
    (
    MAX(MEMBER_VALUE)
        for x.MEMBER_PROPERTY in (' + @cols + ')
    ) p'
execute sp_executesql @query;
drop table #MEMBER_ATTRIBUTES
```