# Getting Null data while using PIVOT in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am using the following query with PIVOT:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
     SELECT 
         MEMBER_PROPERTY as [MEMBER_PROPERTY],MEMBER_VALUE as MEMBER_VALUE, 
         MEMBER_ID as MEMBER_ID 
         FROM MEMBER_ATTRIBUTES) as s
   PIVOT
(
     max(MEMBER_PROPERTY)
     FOR [MEMBER_VALUE] IN (['My main interests'], traveling,accommodation, prizedraw)
)AS test
```

This query returns Null for "['My main interests'], traveling,accommodation, prizedraw" columns, i am not getting why, as the table has data for these columns for each record..

Please help me how can I get data.

UPDATE ::

[image: Multiple records from database]

Comment: Try just `[My main interests]` (without quotes).

Comment: @Bharadwaj still having the same result..

Comment: I just executed sample code in my pc, its working fine without quotes, but getting `null` with single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help you.we should use QuoteName function for space column.

```
    CREATE Table  #MEMBER_ATTRIBUTES  (
MA_ID int,
MEMBER_ID int,
MEMBER_PROPERTY varchar(100),
MEMBER_VALUE varchar(100)
)

insert INTO #MEMBER_ATTRIBUTES values(1,1,'My Main Interests','traveling')
insert INTO #MEMBER_ATTRIBUTES values(2,1,'I m Most Likly to be travelling','With a parents')
insert INTO #MEMBER_ATTRIBUTES values(3,2,'My Main Interests','prizedraw')
insert INTO #MEMBER_ATTRIBUTES values(4,2,'I m Most Likly to be travelling','With my wife')


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols= stuff((
            SELECT ', ' +QUOTENAME(MAX(MEMBER_PROPERTY))
            FROM #MEMBER_ATTRIBUTES
            group by MEMBER_PROPERTY
            order by MEMBER_PROPERTY
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '');

SET @query = 'SELECT MA_ID,MEMBER_ID, ' + @cols + '
            from 
             (
                   SELECT MA_ID,MEMBER_PROPERTY as [MEMBER_PROPERTY],MEMBER_VALUE as MEMBER_VALUE, 
     MEMBER_ID as MEMBER_ID  FROM #MEMBER_ATTRIBUTES
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
            MAX(MEMBER_VALUE)
                for x.MEMBER_PROPERTY in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p'

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: as per my sample value this will work.if you want dynamic cols give me your table structure and sample data. i will execute locally.

Comment: i have update my question data and table structure, please check\

Comment: thanks for updating i have edited my post could you please quick check. if it is not giving the expected result.post you expected answer also.